# After dual boot install data on hard disk is partially gone

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

After copying my win7 on ssd drive i perform install of Ubuntu, after login on ubuntu i have trouble to view data on my ntfs hard disk drive, first it was visible and then it show that a folder is empty. Before booting on win 7, check disk started to perform some fixes, after that i lose on one partition 20 gb, on other 80 gb.  My mistake is that i have low disk space on evry partition and i didnt perform restore point. Did my data is lose for ever or is posible to recover. And my trouble is after login Ubuntu, win 7 perform disk check every time ...what that can mean? Btw, when i restart in win 7 its boot normal without any changes on data or starting check disk.But when i log on win7 after ubuntu i lose again some data. Some of data is placed in found win folder but some is reduced to 0 kb.

Comment: This sounds like something is causing filesystem corruption. This is common in Windows 8 and later because of the Fast Startup and Hibernate features, but this isn't likely in Windows 7 unless you're hibernating rather than shutting down. If this is the case, be sure to perform full shutdowns; hibernating when dual-booting is a recipe for disaster!

Comment: I didnt perform hibernate, thats hapend after restarting system. Btw checkdisk is detected file system corruption.

Comment: is any way to recover data ?

Comment: This does sound like the Windows 8 and later Fast Startup problem. Perhaps you've changed a setting or added software that causes something similar to happen in Windows 7...? Another possibility might be some software that's causing the shutdown to fail to properly unmount the partition. These are just wild guesses, though; on Windows 7, this type of problem is rare. As to data recovery, as it's an NTFS partition, you should ask about that on a Windows forum. There are no good NTFS maintenance tools for Ubuntu. (Note that `ntfsfix` is, at best, a very poor NTFS maintenance tool.)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the NTFS-3g drivers that Ubuntu uses were developed through reverse engineering. Although they're pretty reliable, they may well rely on assumptions or conclusions that aren't quite 100% correct. In my comments, I note that your problem sounds like a Windows 8-or-later Fast Startup problem, and I stand by that assessment; however, it could also be that you've run into a bug in the NTFS-3g driver that's causing it to misbehave because of some unusual (but legal) aspect of your NTFS partition.

To minimize the risk of such problems, if you don't need access to an NTFS volume in Ubuntu, you should ensure that it's *not* mounted. You can do this by editing `/etc/fstab` and adding a line like this:

```
/dev/sda1  /media/windowsHDD  ntfs  noauto  0 0
```

This tells the computer to *not* mount `/dev/sda1` (change that to identify your NTFS partition) at `/media/windowsHDD`. You could still mount it by typing `sudo mount /media/windowsHDD`, provided that mount point exists.

To minimize the risk of problems like what you're experiencing, many people set aside a dedicated data-exchange partition, leaving the Windows `C:` partition unmounted. This may require repartitioning your disk, though; and if you want complete and unfettered access to all your user data from both OSes, all your data will remain at risk. I recommend using FAT for the data-exchange partition if that's practical, because Linux's FAT drivers are older and more robust than Linux's NTFS drivers. The problem, of course, is that FAT is a much more limiting filesystem. In particular, it can't handle files larger than about 4 GB. NTFS also provides more features in Windows, so if you use the partition mainly in Windows, NTFS may be preferable.

As to repair, as noted in my comment, you should ask about that on a Windows forum. There are no good Ubuntu NTFS repair tools (`ntfsfix` is *not* a good repair tool!), and the expertise on this matter exists on the Windows forums.

Comment: Thanx for advice.